# Should I provide the highest quality image for the next.js Image component?

Tags: next.js

If I supply the Image component with **100% JPGs** or **2x sized PNGs**, does it affect the performance of the website (and the SEO at the end)? I noticed that If I provide the optimised quality and size, it decreases the actual image shown on the web page. Like for instance I supply with **JPG 700x700px**, it reduces to **25kb**, but the quality of the shown image is poor. And I don't want to play with the default quality setting of the Image component which is **75**. So the solution here is to supply the Image Component with the original file, which can be big, like **1mb** or so.

Like should I think about Image component as I provide an original image and it takes care about sizes, optimisations and everything performance while I am relaxing?

Basically, I am trying to understand the right approach of using the Next.js Image component. Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: if you are using next/image then you can pass  quality ={100} . by default quality was 75

Answer (score 0):

You can pass quality prop like this

```
<Image
  src="me.png"
  alt="Picture of the author"
  width={500}
  quality={100}
  height={500}
/>
```